# How can I store settings accessible to multiple applications in .Net?

Tags: .net, settings, preferences

I'm working on a project that has to store settings that will be accessible only to a single application, and also settings that must be accessible to multiple applications (which will be written in the future).

I know in Java that there is the `Preferences` class which has `Preferences.systemRoot()`, a preferences node stored independent of any application node in the system registry (on windows, on OSX I have no idea). I also know that .Net settings are stored in the `%appdata%` directory, which is fine. Whichever works fine for me.

What I need to know is does .Net have a settings equivalent of the Java `Preferences.systemRoot()`?

Comment: What .NET application are you talking about? And besides, the registry should be avoided

Comment: I'm not talking about storing values in the registry, I'm talking about the functionality obtained by Java's Preferences.systemRoot() which allows the storing of values accessible to all programs. That's what I want... hmm guess I didn't really phrase it well though...

Comment: You can use 'Environment.System' value http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Broken_Window: That is the most ludicrous suggestion I've heard in a while.  %system% is ***NOT*** where application setting should be stored.  Ever.  For a whole truckload of reasons.

Comment: @Dan-o Actually, That's pretty much what I was thinking about doing since it seems to be the most straight-forward method for accomplishing what it is I am trying to do.

Comment: @Dan-O: it was a typo, I wanted to point out the Net's Environment enum

Comment: @Broken_Window I figured that out, since my searches lead me to where you were leading me. No worries.

Comment: @Will it's ok. Sometimes SO is a hostile place, no worries :)

Comment: One option is to have each application write to it's own local config.  Each time it each app has access to the database it synchs.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in functionality for this.

You have several options though - in no particular order.

> 1. Store the settings as a file in %AppData%
> 2. Store the settings in a database
> 3. Store the settings in the registry (as others have mentioned, this is not a great idea).
> 4. Store the settings in "the cloud".

An example of option 1 would be:

```
Dim settingsDirectory as String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
Dim fileName As String = "the name of the settings file.xml"
Dim settingsPath As String = String.Empty

settingsDirectory = Path.Combine(settingsDirectory, "Your Company Name here")
If Not Directory.Exists(settingsDirectory) Then
  Directory.Create(settingsDirectory)
End If
settingsPath = Path.Combine(settingsDirectory, fileName)
'  Read or write your settings file here.
```

There are many viable options.  This is by no means an exhaustive list.  Each option has its pros and cons, which you will need to noodle out for your particular use case.

Comment: We are storing the values on a database, however we need a fallback because our clients are paranoid little gazelle that run their systems offline for... reasons. As for your list of options, I do like #1, which is for what I was going, but I need to know how about I would go accessing that particular settings object from multiple different applications.

Comment: Thanks. That's not entirely what I had in mind, I wanted to take advantage of the .Net Settings API (probably not the appropriate vernacular).

Comment: As long as your settings files conform to .NET's idea of a configuration file you can use the ConfigurationManager http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx to work with them.

Comment: Although, honestly, its much easier to just create a common settings class library and de/serialize the objects to your favorite format.